# Multisorting in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I sort on multiple columns? I tried using this expression:

```
if (name != null)
{
    if (name.Equals(SortEnum.ASC))
    {
        employees = employees.OrderBy(e => e.Name);
    }
    else if (name.Equals(SortEnum.DESC))
    {
        employees = employees.OrderByDescending(e => e.Name);
    }
}

if (surname != null)
{
     if (surname.Equals(SortEnum.ASC))
     {
         employees = employees.OrderBy(e => e.Surname);
     }
     else if (surname.Equals(SortEnum.DESC))
     {
         employees = employees.OrderByDescending(e => e.Surname);
     }
}
```

But only the last column becomes sorted. Somewhere I saw method `ThenBy()`, but I don't have it.
Please help.

Comment: You can't use `ThenBy()` after the `OrderBy`? That's strange.

Comment: Really strange, this should work `employees.OrderBy(e => e.Name).ThenBy(e => e.Surname);` OR `employees.OrderByDescending(e => e.Name).ThenByDescending(e => e.Surname);`

Comment: Indeed I can, but only after method OrderBy. In my example I can't use it.

Comment: You mean to say you need to check what direction `name` and `surname` hold and then use the appropriate ordering?

Comment: @Nilesh Yes, I meant it.

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible without some extension. [Here](http://aonnull.blogspot.in/2010/08/dynamic-sql-like-linq-orderby-extension.html) is one I found. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `System.Linq.Dynamic`

```
List<string> orderstr = new List<string>();
orderstr.Add((name != null)? name.Equals(SortEnum.ASC)? "Name ASC": "Name DESC" : string.Empty);
orderstr.Add((surname != null)? surname.Equals(SortEnum.ASC)? "Surname ASC": "Surname DESC" : string.Empty);
var reslt = employees.OrderBy(string.Join(", ",orderstr.Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))));
```